# ajax synchronous call problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajax-request, sjax

I have an Ajax function which looks like :

```
  function getData(p) {
  loadingImage();
  p = p.replace("frame_", "");
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {              
    AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();              
  } else {                                  
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (AJAX) {
     var __page =encodeURIComponent(p);
     AJAX.open("GET", "page.php?page="+__page, false);                             
     AJAX.send(null);
     var __data = AJAX.responseText.match(/<data>[\s\S]*?<\/data>/gmi);
     if(!__data) { return false; }
     return __data;      
  } else {
     return false;
  }      
}
```

then i have very simple loading function ( an loading image must appear in center of page ) :

```
function loadingImage(type)
{
   document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "<div class='loading'></div>";
}
```

then how i call ajax function :

```
 var loadedData = getData("home");
 if(loadedData)
 {
   document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = loadedData;
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Error";
 }
```

but the loading image won't appear, it's quite simple, but i'm stuck here , how make it to show that loading image while requesting data, then to replace loading image with loaded data. Thanks

Comment: why?.. then which method to use

Comment: _Asynchronous_ JAX. Use the `onreadystatechange` event handler

Comment: Where are you calling the `loadingImage` function?

Comment: @John: see [Synchronous v. Asynchronous](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/04/synchronous-v-asynchronous/) for why you shouldn't use SJAX and how to handle asynchronous requests.

Comment: @Raynos at beginning of the getData function ( edited now, from loading() to loadingImage() )

Comment: @outis thanks, i will try to find an solution, last time when i used Ajax it returned 'undefined' result

Comment: @beeglebug i'd like to not use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getData(p, cb) {
    loadingImage();
    p = p.replace("frame_", "");
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        AJAX = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (AJAX) {
        var __page = encodeURIComponent(p);
        AJAX.open("GET", "page.php?page=" + __page, true);
        AJAX.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (AJAX.readystate === 4) {
                var __data = AJAX.responseText.match(/<data>[\s\S]*?<\/data>/gmi);
                cb(data);
            }
        };
        AJAX.send(null);
    } else {
        cb(null);
    }
}

getData("home", function(loadedData) {
    if (loadedData) {
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = loadedData;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Error";
    }
});
```

Use `async = true` in the `.open` call.

Bind an eventhandler to `readystatechange`. If the `readystate` is 4 (LOADED) then get the data and send it to your callback.

If the AJAX fails call the callback with `null` or `false`.

In your callback get the `loadedData` and either render it or throw an error if there is no data.